# Длина jsonb в postgreSQL 9.4

Tags: json, django, postgresql

Пытаюсь с помощью django-приложения (функция `update_or_create`) занести данные из excel-файла в базу данных в поле `jsonb`. Данные в ячейках длинные - несколько ячеек, в одной из них 8500 символов, остальные до 250 символов, всё записывается в одно поле. Запись данных проходит с ошибкой.

Если сократить текст в самом длинном поле до 5500 символов, то запись проходит успешно, но если оставить 5501, то с ошибкой.

Я не вижу ограничение в 5500 символов у jsonb. Подскажите пожалуйста, где искать проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в том, что поле jsonb в этой модели индексируется командой `db_index=True,` которая создаёт стандартный `b-tree индекс`. Его максимальная длина **2712 символов** и, видимо, эта длина зависит от длины данных.

Теоретически можно поменять в СУБД вручную тип индекса на `gist`, это должно помочь. Было бы здорово, если бы это можно было сделать в модели django, но я не знаю, как.